# Use robots.txt to allow Google to crawl images but not index them

Tags: seo, search-engine-indexing, robots.txt, images

I have problem with on page optimization.  I checked my site to see if it is  compatibility for mobile devices with [Google's tool](https://search.google.com/test/mobile-friendly).
It showed me that page speed was low.  Google also says it cannot access or crawl images because I blocked it with *robots.txt*.

In *robots.txt* I have `Disallow: /wp-content/`. In `/wp-content/` I have all the images for the site. But when I make this folder `allow:` Google indexed my images separately.  When I use the site search `site:buhehe.de`  it shows that Google views each image as a separate page.

What is the best practice? How do I configure *robots.txt* for images? 
For example, here is a page  with images: http://buhehe.de/itunes-musik-auf-iphone-compressor/

Comment: It isn't usually a problem that Google indexes your images.   They usually only appear in image search.   There isn't a ton of value in having images indexed, but there isn't any harm either.

Comment: `User-agent: *
Disallow: /wp-content/` should do the trick